# RegEx to find compound words

Tags: regex

I wrote this regular expression

```
[Cc]ommercial \b(([Cc]omputer )?(software|source code)?\b)|([Oo]ff((-)?|( )?)[Tt]he((-)?|( )?)[Ss]helf|item)
```

to match on these words:

> “commercial software” OR “COTS” OR “Commercial Off-the-shelf” OR “Commercial-Off-The-shelf” OR “Commercial off the shelf” OR “commercial item” OR “commercial computer software” OR “commercial source code” OR “commercial computer source code”

but I don't want "commercial computer" on it's own to match. How can I fix my regEx?

Comment: The requirements are way too varied for a regex usage IMO, better to separate into smaller regex cases where each group contains similar requirements. Too hard to maintain or to read what that regex is doing really.

Comment: If you want to match withing the curly quotes add them to the pattern, see https://regex101.com/r/d0U942/1

Answer (score -1):

This works well and allows you to omit plurals

```
([Cc]ommercial ((\bcomputer\b )?(\bsoftware\b|source \bcode\b)|\bitem\b|[Oo]ff(-)?( )?[Tt]he(-)?( )?[Ss]helf))|\bCOTS\b
```